# Correct way to structure RESTful service code

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am newbie in writing RESTful service using Jersey. Following is sample code.

I created a class "User" & put everything inside that class.

```
// Service to get the user information

@Path("/User")
public class User {

@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getloggedinuser")
    public String getUserInfo(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

                   // Some code to get the user information
    // Call M1
    M1();
}

private void M1(){
// Some other business logic

// Call another method
M2();
}

private void M2(){
// Some other business logic
}


}
```

Can anybody please tell me the better ways to structure my service. I have few ideas but not sure if those  actually good or shall I keep my current implementation.

Questions

1. The service class (User) has the concrete implementation. Is this a good idea to create an interface (say IUser) and do a implementation of User class??
2. Shall I create a controller class & inject IUser as dependency in the controller? Does Jersey provides any out of box functionality create controller class.

Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I often do is to combine Spring and Jersey. 
Jersey handles all Request/Response and Representation (through factories and/or builder) related things.
The Spring @Service handles all business logic, persistence etc.

So the Resource accepts (or don't) the request, delegates it to the service (that returns the result as model to the resource), and the resource transforms this model to the matching (Json or XML, or something alike) representation and returns it as the response.

The benefits I see here is, clear communication (and auth) in the resource, business logic exclusively in the @Service, inter-component communication with model-objects and communication with clients through representation-objects.

Comment: this also might help: https://www.toptal.com/spring/top-10-most-common-spring-framework-mistakes

Answer (score 0):

There are many guidelines out there that will contradict each other on the details, but largely follow similar patterns when it comes to designing your REST structure.

Personally I use the following in your instance: `/v1/users`  If the requesting user has permissions they likely would see an array of all the users of the system.

I avoid writing sentences as REST paths.  Instead to get the current logged in user I would create something along the lines of

`/v1/users/me`

This would be equivalent to

`/v1/users/123` (123 is my user_id)

Here's a decent tutorial article that covers the basics.

https://blog.qmo.io/ultimate-guide-to-api-design/